# Opening file in iOS from iCloud, Google Drive, Dropbox etc

Tags: android, ios

I'm porting an app developed in Android to iOS.

Within the app, the user should be able to import some zip files. To pick those files, the user can select any available source, including internal storage, file managers, google drive, dropbox etc. This is handled by Android by simply doing like this:

```
String mimetype = "application/zip";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType(mimetype);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

I'm wondering if there is a similar thing in iOS. By reading the documentation, I learned that Apps are sanboxed and cannot access contents outside their "island". But then I have found this from Apple official documentation, that should do what I'm looking for.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

However it seems just a preliminary design documentation so far. Not available yet. Is that right?
Is there anything that could help me now?

Comment: As of iOS 8, look at `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.